# Simulate key holding for a specified time

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm currently trying to simulate holding a key down for a specified time. The code runs in its own thread so it's not interrupting the UI. But the `Sleep` function is still interrupting the hold sequence. I actually wanted to use `Sleep` for the time, the key has to be hold down. Is there any way around?

```
int delay = 2000;

keybd_event(VK_W, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
keybd_event(VK_W, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
```

This should simulate holding down the key `W`, but all it does is pressing it, sleeping (it doesn't do anything), and then releasing it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to repeatedly send key-down strokes for a specified number of milliseconds, this could work, but you don't know how many times it's really being pressed - you just know that it's being pressed for the duration of 2000 milliseconds at some unknown discrete rate.

```
public void DoFor(Action action, int numMilliseconds)
    {
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

        while (DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).TotalMilliseconds < numMilliseconds)
        {
            // Not sure - is this relevant on another thread?
            Application.DoEvents();
            // Not sure if this is relevant either since you're on another thread
            Thread.Sleep(1);
            // Do your action
            action();
        }
    }
```

And you could call it like so:

```
        DoFor(new Action(() =>
                             {
                                 keybd_event(VK_W, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
                             }), 2000);
        DoFor(new Action(() =>
                             {
                                 keybd_event(VK_W, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
                             }), 50);
```

Comment: I'm planning on using my programm as a macro on a game.
It doesn't matter how many times the key has been drawn, I just need the key to be continuously pressed down, otherwise I may could get muted on the server (or even kicked). Is sending lots of key down events like holding the key? Or does it actually send a keyup event if it gets triggered repeatedly?

Comment: I just tried your method but it doesn't work. It loops through the code but it has the same behavior as with the `Sleep` function. Strange...

Comment: Oh sorry I did a mistake, seems to work. I hope it'll count as a hold in the game though. Thank you for your help. ;)

Comment: What game is this? Just wondering why they don't block simulated input.

Comment: Hitomi, Did you get this working? I am trying to do the same thing. I need to simulate holding control while doing a left mouse click. I can't work out the CTRL keydown